# How to format double value for a given locale and number of decimal places?

Tags: java, number-formatting

How can I use `NumberFormat` to format a `double` value for a given `Locale` (default locale is sufficient) and for a given number of decimal places?

For example, I have these values:

```
double d1 = 123456.78;
double d2 = 567890;
```

And I want to print them in the following way, for example with US locale and 2 decimal places:

```
123,456.78
567,890.00
```

I don't actually care about rounding mode in this case, because these double values are gained from a `BigDecimal` with the given scale, so their number of decimal places is always lesser or equal than the number of decimal places I want to print.

**Edit:**

To make things a bit more clear, the thing is that I want to display money in a locale dependent way, but with a fixed number of decimal places. The example above showed, how the values should be formatted if the system locale is `en_US`. Now lets say, the system locale is `cs_CZ` (Czech), so the same numbers should be formatted in this way:

```
123 456,78
567 890,00
```

Now, how can I set up a NumberFormat to always display 2 decimal places, but to display thousands separator and decimal point based on the current locale?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you care to read NumberFormat's documentation, the solution would be obvious:

```
double d1 = 123456.78;
double d2 = 567890;
// self commenting issue, the code is easier to understand
Locale fmtLocale = Locale.getDefault(Category.FORMAT);
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(fmtLocale);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(formatter.format(d1));
System.out.println(formatter.format(d2));
System.out.println(fmtLocale.toLanguageTag());
```

On my machine this prints out:

> 123 456,78
>   567 890,00
>   pl-PL

I believe this is what you are looking for, and you don't have to mess-up with patterns. I wouldn't do that - for instance there are locales which group digits by two, not by three (this is the reason we talk about **grouping separator** and *not* **thousands separator**).

Comment: @Paweł Dyda How should i convert a string 123,456.78 in US locale to a double value 123456.78?

Answer (score 9):

Adapted from [Customizing Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html),

```
  public void localizedFormat(double value,Locale loc ) {

  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(loc);
  DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
  df.applyPattern("###,###.00");
  String output = df.format(value);

  }
```

This function should give you the required formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
formatter.applyPattern("#,###,##0.00");
formatter.format(yourDoubleHere)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but similar to other answers I wrote this to have a quick solution

```
public static String formatDecimal(Double decimal) {
        return new DecimalFormat(
                "###,###,###,###.##",
                DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
        )
                .format(decimal);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

converts a double value to a double value with any number of digits after decimal.
I have created this method in a Utility class to access it through out the project.

```
public static double convertToDecimal(double doubleValue, int numOfDecimals)  {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(doubleValue);
        bd = bd.setScale(numOfDecimals, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
```