# DecimalFormat , input 123.45 , expect 0123.4500

Tags: java

input :123.45.

expect output : 0123.4500

In my netbean 8.02 jdk 8 the result when I run the following code is: 0123,4500

In other compile online site (tutorialspoint/ ideone) the result is : 0123.4500

I don't understand why my result have the comma instead of dot?
Anyhelp can give me expect output is 0123.4500 ??

```
public class MainClass{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String out="";
        String Format="0000.0000";
        DecimalFormat dfm=new DecimalFormat(Format);
        out=dfm.format(123.45);
        System.out.println("out="+out);
        }
}
```

Comment: Try ####.#### instead of 0000.0000, i think this will help.

Comment: it might be a locale issue. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411414/how-to-format-double-value-for-a-given-locale-and-number-of-decimal-places

Comment: It needs to use localised format (###,###.###      123,456.789     en_US) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point

Answer (score 3):

The comma comes from the Locale on your system. Try setting the default Locale like this

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

or setting the Locale specificly for this DecimalFormat. Here is one way to do that

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
DecimalFormat dfm = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why my result have the comma instead of dot?

That might be because of your locale setting. [There are countries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) which use comma as a separator for decimals.

Try to set your locale as:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/evTVJF)**

Comment: "some countries"? [Like 74 countries with a comma, for 47 with a decimal point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire:- Updated that. Hope that makes it better :P